# CMake Error: "Could not find QCA"

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to run CMake on the latest clone of [QGIS](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS), but I'm getting this error:

```
Found SpatiaLite: C:/OSGeo4W/lib/spatialite_i.lib
Looking for gaiaDropTable in C:/OSGeo4W/lib/spatialite_i.lib
Looking for gaiaDropTable in C:/OSGeo4W/lib/spatialite_i.lib - found
Looking for gaiaStatisticsInvalidate in C:/OSGeo4W/lib/spatialite_i.lib
Looking for gaiaStatisticsInvalidate in C:/OSGeo4W/lib/spatialite_i.lib - not found
Looking for spatialite_init_ex in C:/OSGeo4W/lib/spatialite_i.lib
Looking for spatialite_init_ex in C:/OSGeo4W/lib/spatialite_i.lib - found
...
...
CMake Error at cmake/FindQCA.cmake:58 (message):
  Could not find QCA
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:312 (FIND_PACKAGE)
```

Did I set up the build process incorrectly? I'd appreciate any and all help, thanks!

Comment: Have you QCA installed? I don't know what it is, but that's the error message. Spatialite is found so it does not seem to trigger the error.

Comment: Thanks! Installing qca-dlevel totally worked. I was obsessing over the missing function since that's all that was mentioned in the error logs. I'll edit the question. I'd definitely mark your answer if you'll post one officially.

Comment: I had the same issue compiling with mock on Fedora's COPR. Confirmed, adding "BuildRequires:  qca-devel" helps also for the RPM compilation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install `libqca2-dev`.

```
sudo apt-get install libqca2-dev
```

I also had to change the `WITH_QWTPOLAR` flag to `OFF` (on the ccmake gui) to be able to compile the sources.

These were the only things I've changed to compile QGIS. I've followed the available [documentation to build QGIS](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.github.com/qgis/QGIS/master/doc/INSTALL.html).

Comment: On current Debian (2023), `libqca2-dev` is not present; instead, I ran `sudo apt install libqca-qt5-2-dev`.